# How to save multiple object in storage in Chrome Extentions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

After each click on the page I get the following object with a different `time`.

```
var obj = {"time" : "23:10", "total" : 3, "priory" : "1"}
```

So, how can I save this object in local storage Google Chrome, that after I can take all rows sorted by `time`, or `total`?

As I know Chrome Storage allows to store only `key => value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that Local Storage is a key/value store. However, the value can be anything you want. Right now you just have a simple object literal.

One option would be to store an array of these objects as one item in Local Storage. You need to update the existing array for each click event and push the updated version.

In Chrome Extensions, the [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API is used instead of the standard [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API, as it requires different scoping. It is very similar, but it's asynchronous, and it provides some additional functionality for extensions.

```js
function updateLocalChromeStorage(key, obj) {
   var myObjArray = [];

   chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(result) {
       if (result) { 
           myObjArray = result[key];
       }

       myObjArray.push(obj);

       chrome.storage.local.set({key: myObjArray}, function() {
           console.log('Updated myObjArray in storage');
       });
   });
}

// in your click handler, pass the newly constructed object to the update function
button.onclick = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var obj = {"time" : now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes(), "total" : 3, "priory" : "1"};
    updateLocalChromeStorage('myObjArray', obj);
}
```

You can then sort the array when you finally need it:

```js
function getSortedObjArray(key, sort) {
    var myObjArray = [];

    chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(result) {
       console.log('Received myObjArray from storage');
       myObjArray = result[key];
       sort(myObjArray);
   });
}

getSortedObjArray('myObjArray', function(myObjArray) {
    var mySortedObjArray = myObjArray.slice().sort(function(first, second) {
        return first.total - second.total;
    });

    // do something with the sorted array.
});
```

This will sort based on `total`, ascending, and return an array. You may wonder why I used `slice()` before sorting. The reason is that the native `sort` function mutates the array, rather than return a new one (i.e. it's not pure). A workaround is to use `slice()`, which returns a new array. In ES6, you can use the spread operator to achieve the same thing.

IndexedDB is another solution which is possibly better for storing very large amounts of structured data. I have not used it before, but you can read [Using IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) to get an idea of how it works, and whether it would be applicable for the scale of your app.

Personally, if you find Local Storage to be performing well enough, go with that. It's a dead simple API, and you may find the learning curve for IndexedDB to outweigh the benefit over Local Storage.

Comment: Updated answer to make the `sort` pure so as to maintain the natural sort of the storage version.