# Storing object in Chrome Extension: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I was trying to store object in Chrome storage based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792988/how-to-save-multiple-object-in-storage-in-chrome-extentions).

Update storage

```
function updateLocalChromeStorage(key, obj) {
    var myObjArray = [];
    chrome.storage.local.get(key, function (result) {
        if (result) {
            myObjArray = result[key];
        }
        myObjArray.push(obj);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ key: myObjArray });
    });
}
```

Current tab url function

```
function getCurrentTabUrl(callback) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        var url = new URL(tab.url)
        var domain = url.hostname;
        callback(domain);
    });
}
```

Click event

```
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (document.getElementById('block').checked) {
        getCurrentTabUrl(function (url) {
            updateLocalChromeStorage('myObjArray', url);
        });
    }
});
```

This is getting error `Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around by re-writing the click event and incorporating `updateLocalChromeStorage` function activities in the event.

```
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (document.getElementById('block').checked) {
        getCurrentTabUrl(url => {
            chrome.storage.sync.get('blockedUrl', ({ blockedUrl = [] }) => {
                blockedUrl.push([url]);
                chrome.storage.sync.set({ blockedUrl });
            });
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap "key" in square brackets

```
function updateLocalChromeStorage(key, obj) {
    var myObjArray = [];
    chrome.storage.local.get([key], function (result) {
        if (result[key]) {
            myObjArray = result[key];
        }
        myObjArray.push(obj);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ [key]: myObjArray });
    });
}
```

Comment: now it should work. Keep the square brackets

Comment: @wOxxOm: if you don't use square brackets with "storage.local.set" you'will found out an item in storage.local called  KEY.

Comment: Ah, you mean the literal `[key]: value`, I see! Indeed, there were two mistakes.

Comment: The error is no longer there, but not getting expected result which is storing object. I found a solution without using ```updateLocalChromeStorage``` function. I am posting it as answer.